# get the value of input type file , and alert if empty

Tags: jquery

how to alert if input type file is empty !?

this is my jquery code but i didnt know how to get the value

```
$('.upload').live("click",function()
{
    var imgVal = $('#uploadImage').val();
    if(imgVal=='')
    {
        alert("empty input file");

    }
    return false;

});


<input type="file" name="image" id="uploadImage" size="30" />
<input type="submit" name="upload"  class="send_upload" value="upload" />
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#upload').bind("click",function() 
    { 
        var imgVal = $('#uploadImage').val(); 
        if(imgVal=='') 
        { 
            alert("empty input file"); 

        } 
        return false; 

    }); 
});
</script> 

<input type="file" name="image" id="uploadImage" size="30" /> 
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload"  class="send_upload" value="upload" />
```

Comment: pay close attention, i added an ID tag to the upload button and changed your selector and function used to assign the event handler.

Comment: @Fosco is right the problem is that `$(".upload")` won't bind to button as it has `send_upload` applied to it. `upload` is its ID.

Comment: hey! one confusion, cant we directly use `send_upload` instead of creating new ID for the button, `@(".send_upload").bind("click", function(){//code})`

Comment: @Murtaza I don't see why not, as long as it's the only element with that class...  I personally prefer to use ID's for buttons.

Answer (score 6):

There should be

```
$('.send_upload')
```

but not `$('.upload')`

Answer (score 4):

HTML Code

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="uploadImage" size="30" />
<input type="submit" name="upload"  class="send_upload" value="upload" />
```

jQuery Code using **bind** method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#upload').bind("click",function() 
    { if(!$('#uploadImage').val()){
                alert("empty");
                return false;} });  });
```