# JQuery won't check if value of input of type file is null?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a form that must pass validation via JQuery to see if the fields are not null. In my form, I have `<input type="file" id="file"></input>`. When I run the following code, it doesn't work. Can someone shed some light on this for me? Thanks!

```
$('#check').click(function(){
      $('#submit').hide(200);

        var fileVal = $('#file').val(); 
        if(fileVal=='') 
        { 
            alert("Empty input file"); 

        }
});
```

For those who want more, by "work" I mean that I **do not** get the alert specified when the "check" button is clicked.

**EDIT:**
I spelled something else wrong in my code. >.< I was staring at the screen for 2 hours, so I came here, but thanks anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get the value of input type file , and alert if empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292658/get-the-value-of-input-type-file-and-alert-if-empty)

Comment: Works fine for me  http://jsfiddle.net/EFdGa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. inputFile should be file

```
var fileVal = $('#file').val();
```

Also, you can use a self closing tag for your input.

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "[nice simple way to check if a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348257/is-there-a-nice-simple-way-to-check-if-a-variable-in-javascript-has-a-value)" in JavaScript has a value.

Essentially, you can do this:

```
if (typeof fileVal !== 'undefined' && fileVal !== null) {
   console.log("This is non-empty");
}
else{
    console.log("This is empty");
}
```

Also, since you're using jQuery, you might be able to get a way with:

```
$('#file').text();
```

Though, I'd recommend making your element's ID different than it's type, i.e. `id="myFileInput"`

Answer (score 0):

where is your `#inputFile`.i think that is
`$('#file').val();`